# BouncyCastle - Convert X509CrlEntry.SerialNumber to "CAPI-style" hex string

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I am trying to use Org.BouncyCastle.X509 to dump the contents of Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs). In this use-case, I need to get the list of cert serial numbers in their "hexidecimal" string representation, as they appear in the Certificates MMC snap-in (an example value would be **16a03c2c000000000594**).

I am able to get to the point where I have a collection of X509CRLEntry objects to iterate through, but the **SerialNumber** property is of type **Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger**.  This type has an implementation of **ToString()** however, the value returned isn't usable to me:

```cs
public CRLProc(string CRLFile)
        {
            X509CrlParser Parser = new X509CrlParser();
            X509Crl CRL = Parser.ReadCrl(File.ReadAllBytes(CRLFile));
            NextUpdate = CRL.NextUpdate.Value;
            var RevokedCerts = CRL.GetRevokedCertificates();

            foreach(X509CrlEntry entry in RevokedCerts)
            {
                //Target value (first SN in CRL): 16a03c2c000000000594

                string serialNumber = entry.SerialNumber.ToString();
                //serialNumber = "106847877515466973906324" (Nope)

                string serialFromBytes = Encoding.Default.GetString(entry.SerialNumber.ToByteArray());
                //serialFromBytes = "\u0016 <,\0\0\0\0\u0005”" (That's a hard NO)

                string serialFromBigInt = entry.SerialNumber.LongValue.ToString("X");
                //serialFromBigInt = "3C2C000000000594" (OK, now we're getting somewhere!!)
            }
```

So, it looks like [LongValue.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) FTW, but the last piece of the puzzle is how to derive the first 2 octets of the serial number ("16 a0"). Looking for advice on that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want the serial number as a hexadecimal string, BigInteger has an overload of ToString that takes a radix, e.g.:

```
string serialFromBigInt = entry.SerialNumber.ToString(16);
```